# Refactoring Javascript Replace Method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to refactor the javascript replace method. I will need to call this same method on many different variables and am unsure of the best practices for refactoring.

```
function profitMargin(){
var revenue = jQuery("#revenue").val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var profit = jQuery("#profit").val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var profitMar = (profit/revenue*100).toFixed(4);
```

Comment: You can always create a new function. Say, `dropNumericPrefix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to repeat the same regular expression everywhere you can put that in a variable:

```
var reNonNumeric = /[^\d.-]/g;
// and then later
var revenue = jQuery("#revenue").val().replace(reNonNumeric, '');
var profit = jQuery("#profit").val().replace(reNonNumeric, '');
// etc.
```

That makes your code a bit more efficient in that it only creates one regex object, and a bit more descriptive (depending on how you name the variable).

Or you could create a function to do that type of replacement:

```
function removeNonNumericCharacters(val) {
  return val.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
}

// which you'd use later with:
var revenue = removeNonNumericCharacters( jQuery("#revenue").val() );
var profit = removeNonNumericCharacters( jQuery("#profit").val() );
```

Note that either way your `revenue` and `profit` variables will contain strings. The `/` operator converts its operands to numbers, but the regex replace you're doing doesn't actually assure that such conversion is possible: the user may have entered "-..-", which your regex would accept but which obviously isn't a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.yourFunction = function () {
    return this.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
}

var revenue = jQuery("#revenue").val().yourFunction();
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @nnnnnn's answer, you can also store jquery elements in variables to avoid to find them in the DOM each time you call the function.

```
var $revenue = jQuery("#revenue"),
    $profit = jQuery("#profit");



// Later in your function
var revenue = $revenue.val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var profit = $profit.val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
```